# Using \usebox inside a \newcommand

Tags: boxes, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I have this code:

```
%Abstracts
\newcommand{\@spanishabstractname}{{\bfseries Resumen}}
\newsavebox\@sabstract
\newenvironment{spanishabstract}{%
    \lrbox\@sabstract\minipage{1\textwidth}\selectlanguage{spanish}\itshape}%
    {\endminipage\endlrbox\normalfont}

\newcommand{\@englishabstractname}{{\bfseries Abstract}}
\newsavebox\@eabstract
\newenvironment{englishabstract}{%
    \lrbox\@eabstract\minipage{1\textwidth}\selectlanguage{english}\itshape}%
    {\endminipage\endlrbox\normalfont}

%Making Title
\newcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \twocolumn[%
    {\centering \@spanishabstractname\par}\linespace
    \noindent\usebox{\@sabstract}\par\linespace
    \@skeyw\par\onecmskip
    {\centering \@englishabstractname\par}\linespace
    \noindent\usebox{\@eabstract}\par\linespace
    \@ekeyw
    ]
}
```

But when I use the command `\maketitle` in the document, not shows the boxes `\@sabstract` and `\@eabstract`, as follows.

[image: Using maketitle]

If I put the code definition of `\maketitle` in a `\AtEndDocument`:

```
\AtEndDocument{%
    \twocolumn[%
    {\centering \@spanishabstractname\par}\linespace
    \noindent\usebox{\@sabstract}\par\linespace
    \@skeyw\par\onecmskip
    {\centering \@englishabstractname\par}\linespace
    \noindent\usebox{\@eabstract}\par\linespace
    \@ekeyw
    ]
}
```

Everything works perfectly!

[image]

How I can fix this? Why wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Without a MWE it's not possible to help you. If I use some fragments of your code it will work.

Comment: @egreg using `\begin{lrbox}` and `\end{lrbox}` it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel the code correspond to a new LaTeX class, how I can give you a MWE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The box is defined in a group (the environment), so it won't be available outside it. You need to set it globally:

```
\newcommand{\@spanishabstractname}{{\bfseries Resumen}}
\newsavebox\@sabstract
\newenvironment{spanishabstract}
  {\begin{lrbox}{8}
   \minipage{1\textwidth}\selectlanguage{spanish}\itshape}
  {\endminipage\end{lrbox}\global\setbox\@sabstract\box8 }
```

Similarly for the English abstract.

Using `\lrbox` and `\endlrbox` is not recommended. I would put the `\bfseries` instruction later (after `\centering`), not in the definition of `\@spanishabstractname`.

Comment: Thanks! @egreg but doesn't works, doing this occurs the same thing of my initial problem.

Comment: @osjerick Then you're doing something wrong with your class. In my test (with what you provide) it works.

Comment: @osjerick Did it work?

Comment: No just I said Thanks! for your time. :) Any idea what might interfere with this in the rest of the code?

Comment: @osjerick Not really. It *must* work.

Comment: Sorry! It's a stupid error, in the main document I put `\maketitle` after the declarations of the abstracts. I go to delete the question, this happens to me because have my mind on another planet.

Comment: @osjerick Of course you have to insert `\maketitle` after the declaration of the abstracts; but without the `\global` trick it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @egreg: the global isn't needed. You don't have any group. And why do you use an extra box8?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create a MWE whereby the following commands I don't know:

- `\@ekeyw`
- `\@skeyw`
- `\linespace`

Here the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
%Abstracts
\newcommand{\@spanishabstractname}{{\bfseries Resumen}}
\newsavebox\@sabstract
\newenvironment{spanishabstract}{%
    \lrbox\@sabstract\minipage{1\textwidth}\selectlanguage{spanish}\itshape}%
    {\endminipage\endlrbox\normalfont}

\newcommand{\@englishabstractname}{{\bfseries Abstract}}
\newsavebox\@eabstract
\newenvironment{englishabstract}{%
    \lrbox\@eabstract\minipage{1\textwidth}\selectlanguage{english}\itshape}%
    {\endminipage\endlrbox\normalfont}

%Making Title
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \twocolumn[%
    {\centering \@spanishabstractname\par}
    \noindent\usebox{\@sabstract}\par
    \par
    {\centering \@englishabstractname\par}
    \noindent\usebox{\@eabstract}\par
    ]
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{spanishabstract}
\blindtext
\end{spanishabstract}
\begin{englishabstract}
\blindtext
\end{englishabstract}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok! They are command that produces: "**Palabras Claves**:..." (`\@skeyw`) and "**Key words**:..." (`\@ekeyw`), and `\linespace` is `\def\linespace{\vspace{17\p@}}`.

Comment: @osjerick: Did you find the error?

Comment: @osjerick: But the example works ;-)